# How to provide names to arguments of a webmethod in JAX-WS based webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I think arguments of a webservice can be given a name using the @WebParam annotation and I am able to do it for a single argument. How can I give names to multiple arguments for a single webmethod? I need the client to have this information.

Comment: you should be able use multiple @WebParam annotations for mutliple params.

Comment: What is the JAX-WS runtime? Or better, what is the application server and its version?